# How to make this dropdown menu work using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, dropdown

**I've been working with this for days. I can't really find the problem, I'm just new to JS btw, I'm searching for days too. I'm losing hope so I'm posting it here. I need multiple dropdown menu, and I supposedly just want to copy this code but this code don't work even in one menu.**

```js
    function dropdownCategory(){

    document.getElementById("category-filter").classList.toggle("show");

}

window.onclick = function(event){
    if(!event.target.matches('.category-list')){
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("category-list");

        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++){
            var openDropdown= dropdowns[i];

            if(openDropdown.classList.contains('show')){
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
    
**this is the CSS**
```

```css
.dropdown{
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #3a3a3a;
  border-left: 2px solid #f57168;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.category-list,  ul li{
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.default-option{
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  font-size: 21px;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
.default-option:hover{
   color: #f44336;
}

/*code for dropdown list Category*/
.category-list{
  
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
   display: none;
}
.category-list ul{
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  
}
.show{
  display: block;
}
**this is HTML**
```

```html
<!--first dropdown-->
<div class="dropdown"> 

      <!-- dropdown list category name-->
     <button class="default-option"  onclick="dropdownCategory()">Category</button> 
     
      <!-- dropdown list for category choices -->
     <div class="category-list" id="category-filter"> 

      <ul> 
       <li><i class="fas fa-utensils">&nbsp;</i>Food & Beverage</li> 
       <li><i class="fas fa-pencil-ruler">&nbsp;</i>Stationery</li> 
       <li><i class="fas fa-laptop">&nbsp;</i>Internet Cafe</li> 
       <li><i class="fas fa-print">&nbsp;</i>Printing Services</li> 
      </ul>

     </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In your javascript code replace event.target.matches('.category-list') to event.target.matches('.default-option').**

function dropdownCategory(){

```
    document.getElementById("category-filter").classList.toggle("show");

}

window.onclick = function(event){
    if(!event.target.matches('.default-option')){
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("category-list");

        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++){
            var openDropdown= dropdowns[i];

            if(openDropdown.classList.contains('show')){
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the link to JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r3v1ktp7/4/

Comment: thank you. it does work from only the code i gave to you, but when I applied it with the whole code it doesnt work